# javascript escape error

Tags: javascript, escaping, jstl

I have a jstl file which consists of a javascript snippet.

```
<res:useJS target="exec-js">
new current.myfunction({
my_arg:{
<c:forEach items="${arguments.value}" var="dataresults" varStatus="loopcount">
    <c:out value="\"${dataresults}\" ${!loopcount.last ? ', ' : ']'}"/>
</c:forEach>
 });
<res:useJS>
```

But when I run it I get an error saying "invalid property id" and when I look at the content - something like this has been passed. `&#034;data_res1&#034,&#034;data_res1&#34,`. I need to have double quotes in the results as that's how I am parsing it in the javascript function. Any ideas on how this could be done?

Comment: And one of the dataresult also has a possibility of & in it's value which again is a special character..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<c:out>` converts special characters to HTML entities to prevent injections.

You can use [StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJavaScript%28java.lang.String%29) from Apache commons to escape your string and then output the plain value with

```
"${escapedText}" ${!loopcount.last ? ', ' : ']'}
```